# How do I run a branch of functions?

Tags: python

I am working on a number guessing game and I want to have a function like
`game(personGuesses)`
and it will the script that makes the bot randomize a number from 1-100 and the player guesses that number. Or if I do
`game(botGuesses)`
it will make the person think of a number and it makes the bot run through a checker to see if the bot is right or wrong. If you need more explanation I basically want to make a function check if the thing inside of the `()` is `personGuesses` or `botGuesses`.

Comment: Please add how you tried?

Comment: It's seems that you haven't tried to code. just do that and paste where you're getting trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would make a function for each scenario, and use an if statement like this:

```
def botGame():
    # Code for bot's turn

def personGame():
    # Code for person's turn

# I don't know how you would determine if the person or bot plays, so I just set it here
personGuesses = True

if personGuesses:
    personGame()
else:
    botGame()
```